# What would be the proper method to approach this assignment to get the Date in the proper arranged or consecutive manner in Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, rdbms

- first the database is a normal single line one but we have to query to get it to the assignment part while creating :

[image: main table]

- the assignment is to arrange the tasks provided with dates in such format
  to create a schedule for workflow
- the motive is to arrange them in kind of this format
  [image: this is how the output should look]

**I have absolutely no clue but have tried couple things with group by and all open to any answers**

sorry but new here please help thank you!`

```
CREATE DATABASE project ;
CREATE TABLE project_phases(
project_id int,
phase varchar(200),
start_date date
);

INSERT INTO project_phases (project_id,phase,start_date)
VALUES (1, 'design', '2021-01-01');

INSERT INTO project_phases (project_id,phase,start_date)
VALUES (1, 'development', '2021-01-02');

INSERT INTO project_phases (project_id,phase,start_date)
VALUES (1, 'deployment', '2021-01-03');`
```

Comment: add expected output for your desired query you want from this dataset

Comment: the first image is the initial table and the second is the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the window function `lead() over()` is a good fit here

```
Select project_id
      ,from_phase   = phase
      ,to_phase     = lead(phase,1) over (partition by project_id order by start_date)
      ,start_date
      ,end_date     = lead(start_date,1) over (partition by project_id order by start_date)
from project_phases
```

**Results**

[image]